# how to make alias ssh-add /bin/bash in bashrc?

Tags: bash, ssh, git, cmd.exe, alias

how does not this work?

`alias push-bb="ssh-agent /bin/bash && ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucker_rsa && git push"`

I assume it cancels at `/bin/bash` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you expect `&&` to work like this:

1. pretend that `ssh-agent /bin/bash` was typed
2. pretend that <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed
3. pretend that `ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa` was typed
4. pretend that <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed…

But that's not how it works. Aliases are not "fake keyboard input", and `&&` is not a "fake Enter key". The shell interprets them *directly as commands*. So it actually works like this:

1. run `ssh-agent /bin/bash`
2. wait for it to exit
3. run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa`
4. wait for it to exit…

---

So, the alias doesn't "cancel" at step 1.

It *did* actually start you a new copy of /bin/bash, and now you have bash running inside bash – they just look identical to each other, so you didn't notice it. But take a closer look at `ps xf` and you'll see:

```
123 xterm
└ 124 bash           waiting for its child (124 ssh-agent) to exit
  └ 678 ssh-agent    waiting for its child (679 bash) to exit
    └ 679 bash       waiting for keyboard input
```

So instead the alias is *waiting for step 1 to finish*.

If you typed `exit` right now, then the 2nd bash would exit (along with ssh-agent), and your alias would *continue* from that point, and all remaining commands would be interpreted in the *original* bash shell.

---

Instead, you probably want this:

```
alias push-bb="ssh-agent /bin/bash -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucker_rsa && git push'"
```

Here, instead of waiting for keyboard input, the "new" bash is directly told to run the remaining two commands.

Comment: Good answer, though strictly `&&` doesn't just equate to "Wait for preceding command to exit" - a standard `;` does that. `&&` will wait for the preceding command to exit and then *only run the second command if the first command returned with a value of '0'*

Comment: I want to do an alias for ssh-agent bash + ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key to work with Ansible. This method does not work. Any recommendation?